# Get line edit value failed from external .exe in C# winform program

Tags: c#

I use windows 7 and VS 2010.

In my C# Winform program. I want to get the value in a line edit of an external .exe file.

I have get all the handle , but failed passing the correct parameters to SendMessage so I could not get the value of TEDIT.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string 
    lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr 
    hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = 
    true)]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString,
        int nMaxCount);


    private static System.Diagnostics.Process p;
    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        IntPtr intptr = FindWindow(null, "COLOR");

        //IntPtr id = FindWindowEx(intptr, IntPtr.Zero, "TEdit", null);
        IntPtr hWndTEDIT = FindWindowByIndex(intptr, 0);
        IntPtr id = FindWindowEx(intptr, hWndTEDIT, "TEdit", null);

        StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(200);

       // SendMessage(id, WM_GETTEXT, buffer, buffer_size);
       // int length = SendMessage(id, WM_GETTEXT, 0, 0).ToInt32();
       // StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
      //  SendMessage(id, WM_GETTEXT, length, builder);
       // LED_value = buffer.ToString();
        LED_value = GetWindowText(id, title, 65536);
        textBox2.AppendText(LED_value.ToString());
    }
    static IntPtr FindWindowByIndex(IntPtr hWndParent, int index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
            return hWndParent;
        else
        {
            int ct = 0;
            IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
            do
            {
                result = FindWindowEx(hWndParent, result, "TEDIT", null);
                if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
                    ++ct;
            }
            while (ct < index && result != IntPtr.Zero);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Although the value in the TEDIT is 171B18. The LED_value is 0 after debugging.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kSQR.png)

Comment: The SendMessage declaration is not correct.  3rd parameter should be IntPtr, pass new IntPtr(title.Capacity).  4th parameter should be StringBuilder.

Comment: pass new IntPtr(title.Capacity) means what? Could pls show me the corrected code?

Comment: I have update it. and still failed